# How to get rid of "You are currently editing a commit"?

Tags: git

Suddenly appeared:

```
MacBook-Pro: $ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up-to-date with 'dropbox/dev'.
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'Releases' on '72ca998'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

No changed in the branch. Everything is up to date.

Comment: have you tried git rebase --continue?

Comment: @NickCatib yes. error: could not apply fbbaa72... Version 0.2.0

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply fbbaa72581bc420fa6c08f342886488e44fc484c... Version 0.2.0

Comment: please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31252363/edit) your question to add details, try not to put them in the comments.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

`git rebase --abort` should abort the rebase operation and return to the previous state. But to be sure, what commands did you enter before?

edit: the output of `git reflog` can show you where the rebase started, it would look something like

```
7d0b010 HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/bran
7d0b010 HEAD@{1}: rebase: adding file in branch
a7e6693 HEAD@{2}: rebase: checkout master
a7e6693 HEAD@{3}: commit: adding file in master
4c00dd7 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from bran to master
3cb192a HEAD@{5}: commit: adding file in branch
```

Answer (score 23):

If you end up in this state but you need to *keep* changes:

1. Make a backup branch of the current branch: `git branch my-backup`
2. On the current branch abort the rebase: `git rebase --abort`
3. Merge changes from the backup branch created in step 1: `git merge my-backup`

Answer (score 11):

try to use
`git rebase --quit`
if `git rebase --abort` failed.

`git rebase --quit` completely discards the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue while working in Xcode. I've noticed that Xcode 14, has a habit of stashing changes, which can cause issues when rebasing.

Aborting the rebase, Quitting Xcode, then re-rebasing worked for me.